# SQL with input condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a customer `table-firstname,lastname,gender,salary`. I am creating a stored procedure with 5 input parameters: `@FN, @LN, @GNDR, @SLRY and @TYPE`.

Now, `if @type=0 and @FN='SAM'` - then,
it should insert a new record in the table, if  'SAM' is already existing in the table.
`if @type=1 and @FN='SAM'` - then,
it should delete a record from the table, if  'SAM' is already existing in the table.
`if @type=2 and @FN='SAM'` - then,
it should update a record in the table if  'SAM' is already existing in the table.

Please help me in creating a query for the above condition.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, this is a product specific issue.

Comment: How us how far you got on your homework. We'll try to fill in the gaps for you.

Comment: Hi Jens I am new to T-SQL, trying with different scenario.

Comment: Just show us what you have right now, how little it might be.

Answer (score 0):

As per given requirement below stored procedure will help you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName (
 @FN VARCHAR(30), @LN VARCHAR(30), @GNDR VARCHAR(30), @SLRY DECIMAL(18,3) , @TYPE INT )
As
BEGIN
         IF @type=0 AND @FN='SAM'
         BEGIN
           --INSERT Command here
         END
         IF @type=1 AND @FN='SAM'
         BEGIN
           --DELETE Command here                  
         END
         IF @type=2 AND @FN='SAM'
         BEGIN
           --UPDATE Command here
         END
END
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `ELSE IF` instead? They seem exclusive enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please check by solution .
Please create different case in SQL Server  .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insertcustomer (
     @FN VARCHAR(30),
     @LN VARCHAR(30),
     @GNDR VARCHAR(30), 
     @SLRY DECIMAL(18,3) , 
     @TYPE INT )
As
BEGIN
         IF @type=0 AND @FN='SAM'
         BEGIN
        Insert into customer(firstname,lastname,gender,salary)values(@FN,
        @LN,@GNDR,@SLRY,@TYPE)  
         END

         IF @type=1 AND @FN='SAM'
         BEGIN
           Delete from customer where firstname= @FN              
         END


         IF @type=2 AND @FN='SAM'
         BEGIN
           update customer set  
           firstname=@FN,lastname=@LN,gender=@GNDR,salary=@SLRY where  
           firstname= @FN 
         END
END
```

It will be work for you .
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

This elaborates on JaydibJ's `PROC`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName (@FN VARCHAR(30), @LN VARCHAR(30), @GNDR VARCHAR(30), @SLRY DECIMAL(18,3) , @TYPE INT )
As
BEGIN
    IF @FN = 'SAM' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE SomeColumn = 'SAM') > 0) --Only check this condition once
        BEGIN
            IF @TYPE=0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT 'SOME VALUE' INTO YourTable WHERE <some condition>
                END
            IF @TYPE=1
                BEGIN
                    DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE <some condition>                
                END
            IF @TYPE=1
             BEGIN
                    UPDATE YourTable
                    SET SomeColumn = 'SomeValue' WHERE <some condition>
             END
        END
    ELSE
    SELECT 'SAM was not supplied in the parameters or did not exist in table' -- or some logic
END
```